# Search engine for man pages

Tags: command-line, man

I needed a function to find a character in a string in c. I used a web browser to search for ”find char in string c” which gave me the information that the function I was looking for is called ”strchr”. I can now do the rest in the terminal with ’man strchr’.

I was wondering however if there is a way to do things like this directly in the terminal. I know of ’man -k’ but it only matches a keyword and it’s not exactly useful to do ’man -k string’.

Comment: I personally use kde-plasma khelpcenter ( https://github.com/KDE/khelpcenter ) which search facilities can optionally be extended to man pages.

Comment: Mot quite what you're looking for but adding fzf or skim would simplify this as in `man -k string | fzf  -f \'chr --no-sort`

Comment: @spinosarus123 It depends on what "things like this" exactly means. Your man implementation may allow you to do, e.g., `apropos -s 2,3 -a '(find|search|locate)' character string` (list manual pages about system and library functions whose summary contains all of "character", "string" and one (at least) of "find", "search" or "locate"). But it'll be of little help if your aim is to search _the Web_ with an engine capable of using synonyms, alternate spellings and some sort of ranking.

Comment: @fra-san This was exactly what I was looking for. Is this a standard implementation on linux?

Comment: @spinosarus123 man-db (the implementation I referred to in my example) is not standard, but it is commonly found on GNU/Linux systems.